# Move element with mouse starts to snap up and down

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a drag on y axis functionality using `mousedown, mousemove` events. The formula is as follows:

```
var position = e.clientY - getOrigin(myDiv).top;
myDiv.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + position + 'px, 0px)';

function getOrigin(elm) {
    ...
    return {
        left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
        top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
    };
}
```

When I drag the element, it snaps up and down really fast. Why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
}

function handleMouseUp(e) {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var position = e.clientY - getOrigin(myDiv).top;
  myDiv.style.transform = 'translate3d(0px, ' + position + 'px, 0px)';
}


function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
#myDiv {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: You're using functions that are unknown to me. Therefor I can't really help you out with this. But if you just want a (pure javascript) solution that works perfectly, I might be able to help you out with that. Just asking first because I can understand you want to understand what's going on what your code.

Comment: @icecub Yes, I want a pure JavaScript solution. Btw, `getOrigin` a function in my code.

Comment: Sorry Jessica, it took me a while to write it for you. Here is a fully functional script: https://jsfiddle.net/vLgg6kez/ . It didn't feel right to put this as an answer to your question because it isn't really. It's just a different solution.

Comment: Before I foget: I've commented the first and last line inside the Javascript code because jsfiddle doesn't like this. You are going to need those lines outside of jsfiddle though! So make sure to remove the comments.

Comment: I've removed a bit of unnessesary code: https://jsfiddle.net/vLgg6kez/1/

Comment: @icecub That works like wonders! Thanks! And if there aren't any other answers, then I think you should post it as one, so you can get the points you deserve. :)

Comment: Alright. Also, the reason your script wasnt working was because `box.top` was returning 2 different values on each pixel movement. Like pixel 1: 50, pixel 2: 85 pixel 3: 51 pixel 4: 86 etc etc. I couldn't figure out why this was happening though. It really shouldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I couldn't exactly figure out what was causing the problem in OPs question (for an unknown reason `box.top` was returning 2 different values alternately on each pixel movement in OPs script), I've written a different script that works perfectly fine:

```js
//document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
 var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

 myDiv.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseDown);
 window.addEventListener('mouseup', handleMouseUp);

 function handleMouseDown(e) {
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove.start(this, 'body',e));
 }

 function handleMouseUp(e) {
  window.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove.stop('body'));
 }

 var mouseMove = function(){
  return {
   move: function(elm, posY){
    elm.style.top = posY + "px";
   },
   start: function(elm, container, e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var posY = e.clientY,
     elmTop = elm.style.top,
     elmHeight = parseInt(elm.style.height),
     conHeight = parseInt(document.getElementById(container).style.height);
    elmTop = elmTop.replace('px','');
    var diffY = posY - elmTop;

    document.onmousemove = function(e){
     e = e || window.event;
     var posY = e.clientY,
      Y = posY - diffY;
     if (Y < 0) Y = 0;
     if (Y + elmHeight > conHeight) Y = conHeight - elmHeight;
     mouseMove.move(elm,Y);
    }
   },
   stop : function(container){
    var a = document.createElement('script');
    document.onmousemove = function(){}
   },
  }
 }();
//});
```

```css
#body {
 margin-top: 50px;
 position: absolute;
}
#myDiv {
 position: absolute;
 background-color: orange;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an off topic question, so don't answer if you don't want to. How can I learn to organize my code like yours? Can you recommend a book, blog or video? Thanks!

Comment: Also, what's the point of the if statement: `if (Y + elmHeight > conHeight)` Does it ever get called?

Comment: @Jessica I honestly learned to organize my coding over the many years of experience I've got (15 years to be precize). I'll see if I can find any interesting sources for you and I'll pass them on later when I find them. On those 2 if statements: They prevent the Div block from moving outside of the document. If you remove them, you can move the Div outside of your screen on top or bottom. Otherwise they will contain it withing the element that has the `id='body'` attribute.

Comment: @Jessica You can try this out yourself if you want to. Just change the CSS code and add this to `#body`: `width: 500px; height: 800px; background-color: blue;`. You'll see that the orange block is now only movable inside the blue block.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jessica I've found an interesting source for you to check out. It'll teach you about Javascript Object Orientated Programming, just like I did in my code above: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript