# Call a returned function from outside its function

Tags: javascript, function, return

I'm trying to call a `function` that's returned from a `function`. Here's what I mean:

```
myFunction.something; // (Wrong)
function myFunction() {
    return {
        something: function() {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

When I try calling `myFunction.something` nothing happens. How can I call a returned function outside of its function?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var index = 0;
var animID = requestAnimationFrame(myFunction.something);

function myFunction() {
  return {
    something: function() {
      index++;
      console.log(index);
      if (index === 5) cancelAnimationFrame(animID);
      else animID = requestAnimationFrame(myFunction.something);
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: try actually calling `myFunction`; `requestAnimationFrame(myFunction().something);`

Comment: @Hamms That works! Is it bad to keep on calling `myFunction()`, or should I make a variable referencing to `myFunction()`, and call the variable?

Comment: it looks pretty bad in this example, yes, but I assume there's some reason why you're hiding your function inside a return value. Without knowing what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to offer advice on how best to achieve it.

Comment: @Hamms I'm trying to organize my code, so I returned all the helper functions in function. This way I can call a helper function like this: `helperFunction.helper1`. I'm trying to 'copy' the method used in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39628878/4861207

Comment: I would first of all recommend using descriptive variable names; `utils` rather than `myFunction`, and `incrementFrame` rather than `something`, for example. I would second of all recommend ignoring that answer and simply putting all of your helper functions directly in an object, then referencing that object.

Comment: @Hamms The difference of the object and a returned function, is that the entire function will get called every time you call a returned function, vs an object, when you call a function in the object, that function will only get called, not all of them. Is that why you suggested using an object over a function?

Comment: There are many more differences than just that, some of them frustratingly subtle. The primary reason I recommend using an object for organization rather than a function which returns an object is because you don't _need_ to use a function for organization; you are unnecessarily complicating your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first of all recommend using descriptive variable names; `utils` rather than `myFunction`, and `incrementFrame` rather than `something`, for example. I would second of all recommend reconsidering your approach to code organization and simply putting all of your helper functions directly in an object, then referencing that object:

```js
var index = 0;
var animID = requestAnimationFrame(utils.incrementFrame);

var utils = {
  incrementFrame: function() {
    index++;
    console.log(index);
    if (index === 5) cancelAnimationFrame(animID);
    else animID = requestAnimationFrame(utils.incrementFrame);
  }
}
```

There are a few differences between these approaches, some of them frustratingly subtle. The primary reason I recommend using an object for organization rather than a function which returns an object is because you don't *need* to use a function for organization; you are unnecessarily complicating your code.

Answer (score 1):

`myfunction` is not the object that you get from calling `myfunction()`, it's the function itself and does not have a `.something` method.

You could call it again (as in `myfunction().something()`), but a better approach would be to store a reference to the object you've already created:

```
function myFunction() {
  var index = 0;
  var o = {
    something: function() {
      index++;
      console.log(index);
      if (index < 5) requestAnimationFrame(o.something);
      // btw you don't need to cancel anything once you reach 5, it's enough to continue not
    }
  };
  return o;
}

myFunction().something();
```

Alternatively you might want to drop the function altogether, or use the module pattern (with an IIFE), as you seem to use it like a singleton anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myFunction().something()
```

- `myFunction()` calls the `myFunction` function
- them we use the dot notation on the returned value (which is an object) to find the `something` member of it
- that member is a function too, so add another set of brackets `()` to call it

Answer (score 0):

Call function after writing it

```js
var index = 0;

function myFunction() {
  return {
    something: function() {
      index++;
      console.log(index);
      if (index === 5) cancelAnimationFrame(animID);
      else animID = requestAnimationFrame(myFunction().something);
    }
  };
}

var animID = requestAnimationFrame(myFunction().something);
```

Comment: Thanks! But with named functions, it doesn't make a difference where you call it. You can define it at the bottom of the page, and call it before.